# Betta laying on bottom

Tags: fish, betta

Our little Betta fish has been laying at the bottom of the tank for a couple days. It will move spots from time to time, but is not swimming around like before. I don’t see any signs of sickness on its fins
We are into day 2 of fasting it. The tank had a filter system and a heater that keeps the water at 78 degrees. I have done a 50% water change. Anything else I can do for the little guy?

Here is a photo: https://m.imgur.com/sHRottI?r

Comment: we have a lot of simmilar questions about bettas on this site so it is likely the answer you are seeking is among them,you might take a look at them by doing a search on this site or take a look at the related questions at the right hand  side of this page.

Comment: Have you tried testing the water's PH levels? I learned from maintaining a family pond that fish are highly sensitive to specific PH ranges in the water.